# Can't Disable "Antialias text" Option Using Menlo Font in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, fonts, terminal, antialiasing

Quite simply, when I'm using the Menlo font in OS X's Terminal.app, the ability to uncheck "Antialias text" is not allowed. The checkbox is disabled, and this only occurs when I'm using the Menlo Regular font face (chosen by default in the Pro theme). See the following screenshot: [Terminal.app Preferences http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/6167/screenshot20110118at702.png](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/6167/screenshot20110118at702.png)
Has anyone experienced this as well? It's really bugging me because I like Menlo as my fixed width font, but I also want it to be aliased for use in Terminal.app. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue with Menlo: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/08/29/first-impressions-of-snow-leopard (search for Menlo)

As long as it's not an issue with my OS or configuration somehow, then I feel a little better about this. Guess I'll stick to Monaco for now...

Answer (score 1):

Having recently installed Lion in a VirtualBox, I'm seeing the same problem. I like nice bitmapped fonts for text editing and terminals.

My take on what's going on is that the `Antialias text` button is actually overloaded with two meanings.

For some bitmapped fonts, it really seems to really turn anti-aliasing on and off. Looking closely at the characters while switching back and forth, you can see that the anti-aliased font is pretty much pixel-for-pixel identical to the bitmapped one, only blurry.

But for some other fonts, it looks as if it selects between an anti-aliased vector font and a hand-made, bitmapped font. E.g. check out Microsoft Sans Serif.

I suspect that the button is disabled in situations when a only a vector font exists.

The ideal situation is when there are separate fonts.

If only a bitmapped font exists, it's okay if the anti-aliasing button works because anti-aliasing a bitmapped font can look passable.

If only a vector font exists, turning off anti-aliasing (especially at those sizes) would look like garbage, so it makes sense to disable the feature.

Sounds like a reasonable hypothesis, anyway.

I'm puzzled, though, why the application does not come configured with a sane default: a good-looking, crisp bitmapped font.

Comment: Tastes vary. I don’t understand why people like bitmap fonts these days. I used to love the bitmap fonts on the original Mac, but these days bitmap fonts look “noisy” to me with all the one-pixel corners and serifs, and Monaco 9pt—my programming font of choice for over a decade—is simply too small on today’s high pixel density displays. Now I stick with (antialiased) Menlo 11 for all monospaced text.

Comment: People like bitmap fonts these days, because finally, thanks to LCD displays having become ubiquitous, bitmap fonts are in a league of their own when it comes to looking sharp. Let's call anti-aliasing what it is: blurring. It's what a CRT does. Or what your eyes do when you're tired.   When you're tired and needa break, bitmap fonts on a LCD help you because the onset of blurry vision is immediate and clear. Anti-aliased fonts conceal the onset of fatigue, and do not give the eye a clear focusing cue.

Comment: Cramming more and more pixels into a display whose size remains about constant is silly. A 19" monitor should not have more than 1280 pixels horizontally. If you want more pixels, get a bigger monitor, so the pixels stay the same size. At my last job, the IT manager though he was doing me a favor by replacing my monitor with a 1600x1280 one while I was out for lunch! Right away I had him take it back and gimme back my 1280x1024. I'm a programmer, not a desktop publisher, and if I was a desktop publisher, I'd want that 1600 in 30 inches.

Answer (score 1):

The antialias checkbox is disabled (and selected) for fonts that do not have bitmaps and therefore must be rendered with (antialiased) outlines. Menlo is one such font.