# Tmux borders are drawn with dashed lines; how can I change them to continuous lines?

Tags: tmux

I'm using Mac OS X Lion, Terminal.app and Tmux version 1.6. I get a dashed line as a window border instead of a continuous line that I get when I ssh into a Debian virtual machine on the same computer using the same terminal. How can I change the dashed line to a continuous line?

Comment: I have the same problem with iTerm2 and tmux 1.6. In Terminal.app however the pane separator is solid and not dashed. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I found some more info, but still no solution. I think the problem is actually a "feature" as described in the change log for Tmux 1.4:

"Use UTF-8 line drawing characters on UTF-8 terminals, thus fixing some terminals (eg putty) which disable the vt100 ACS mode switching sequences in UTF-8 mode. On terminals without ACS, use ASCII equivalents."

Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483798/tmux-borders-displayed-as-x-q-instead-of-lines

Answer (score 38):

I found the origin of the problem. It's the font. I was using *Monaco* and it displays vertical dashes in a way that the vertical pane separator is dashed. With *Menlo* however it's solid.

Comment: Good find. Too bad that anti-aliasing can't be disabled for Menlo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10072765/705157. However, using xterm font `6x13.dfont` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2764467/705157 seems to be a decent non-aliased substitute for Monaco.

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem using iTerm on mac to log into a redhat. Suddenly the vertical lines did not show and the horizontal ones were dashed.

I fixed the problem by unchecking `"Treat ambiguous-width characters as double width"` in `iTerm->Preferences->Profiles->Text`

Comment: This fixed things for me, and also fixed the problem where horizontal box edges in ncurses applications would be drawn double-width, messing up the whole layout. Switching to Menlo from Monaco also helped.

Comment: WHOA! Been like 4 months and I couldn't fix this issue until I saw your answer

Comment: This fixed a problem I was having with getting tmuxline to display properly.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, some fonts you like only contain a small number of glyphs to display usual characters, but failed to include glyphs for other unicode characters, for example U+2502, which is used by tmux as the vertical split line. So the system usually defaults to a fallback font, however, unfortunately, that fallback font does not provide the glyphs that are appropriate for drawing a continuous line.

One possible solution is to use terminals that supports selecting a fallback font, such as iTerm2, then you choose Menlo as you mentioned as the non-ascii font and use the original font as the same time.

The other solution requires a little more work, use fontforge or other font editors to patch the missing glyphs using those from a correctly displayed font like Menlo. Here is a link to what I have done, patching Inconsolata for Powerline using glyphs from Menlo: https://github.com/Determinant/inconsolata_for_powerline_mod

Comment: You're a saint. Thank you for doing that!

Comment: I have a monaco font patched for powerline. I downloaded it a while ago and due to licensing issue, there is no free copy of it. I want to patch U+2502 into this font, I can do it myself or I have another font, a regular Inconsolata font which have nice view of this glyph. Can you explain how I can patch this symbol from inconsolata to monaco?

Comment: @klaus I used fontforge to do the patching, give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

late to the party but might be useful:

- pick a different font for non-ASCII characters
- reduce vertical spacing until vertical separators join into single line