# tmux can not display vertical line when split vertical panel

Tags: putty, tmux

Environment:

- Terminal Client

  - pietty 0.4.0(beta 14) (which is forked from putty)
  - putty 0.63
- OS & tmux version

  - CentOS 6.5, tmux-1.6-3.el6.x86_64
  - ArchLinux, tmux 1.9_a-1

Strange behavior:

- Split a vertical panel.
- It won't display a vertical line between left and right panels.
- When I click on right panels.
- It display a vertical line.

Is there any method to let it always display vertical line?

My tmux.conf

```
set -g utf8
setw -g utf8 on
set-option -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g mouse-resize-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-window on
# I've tried the following three settings, all failed.
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
#set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
#set -g default-terminal "linux"
```

And the TERM and locale variables inside tmux

```
$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE=zh_TW.utf8
```

Comment: Sorry to hear my answer below didn't help. I've since found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14726627/777337) answer. Symptoms are similar to what you have. In the absence of better suggestion, maybe that answer gives you an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In putty/pietty, Turn off the option `change settings`/`Window`/`Translation`/`Treat CJK ambiguous characters as wide`

Answer (score 1):

From the tmux man page:

> The TERM environment variable must be set to ''screen'' for all programs run-ning
>   inside tmux.  New windows will automatically have ''TERM=screen'' added
>   to their environment, but care must be taken not to reset this in shell
>   start-up files.

Maybe try changing this and see if it helps?

I've seen other users usually set this in their `.tmux.conf` so they also get color support:

```
set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'
```